# Catching the exit status of a system command while writing to file

Tags: ruby, system

I am trying to execute a shell command to write into a file in ruby, but i cant get the exit status using `system` :

```
table=File.new('exitStatusTest.txt','w')
exit_status=system(table.puts('ls'))
puts exit_status.to_s
```

This will throw: `exit_status.rb:5:in system': can't convert nil into String`

While i would expect a TrueClass, same as when i use: 
`exit_status=system('ls')`

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Because the result of `table.puts('ls')` is nil, the`system` parameter should be a string.

```
table=File.new('exitStatusTest.txt','w')
output = `ls`
#output might be empty string.
table.puts(output) if not output.empty? # write data into file if output is not empty.
exit_status = !output.empty? # exit_status is true

`ls`.class
=> String
system('ls').class
=> TrueClass
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what are you going to achieve by calling `system` with *a result of `table.puts` as parameter*.

`puts` returns `nil` and hence you are calling `system(nil)`, receiving the very predictable exception.

Assuming you want to execute the command *and* put it into a table, you might try to [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-tap) a string:

```
str = 'ls' # or whatever
exit_status=system(str.tap { |s| table.puts(s) })
```